# My code snippet is leaking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

The below code snippet leaks when i am trying the build and analyse thing.

What is the problem in this code , pls let me know

```
- ( NSString *) getSubCategoryTitle:(NSString*)dbPath:(NSString*)ID{
        NSString *subCategoryTitle;

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        NSString *selectSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"select sub_category_name from sub_categories where id = %@",ID];

        NSLog(@"%@ I am creashes here", selectSQL);

        const char *sql_query_stmt = [selectSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql_query_stmt, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {

            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {

                subCategoryTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                    (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];


            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);    

    }   
    sqlite3_close(database); 


    return [subCategoryTitle autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allocate instance into `subCategoryTitle` in a loop, but don't release the previous allocation.

```
subCategoryTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];
```

Either (auto)release it, or directly go to the last row, and avoid this while, as it doesn't make much sense.

Example for creating only last object:

```
char * col_text = NULL;
while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
{
    col_text = sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0);
}
if (col_text != NULL)
{
    subCategoryTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:col_text];
}
```

Comment: should i create subCategoryTitle with nil value or not

Comment: starting it with nil is fine, but not related to the issue, the issue is that you allocate objects, assign them to `subCategoryTitle` and then override `subCategoryTitle` for a new allocated object (As you are in a loop) without releasing the previous one.

Comment: so should my code look like this [subCategoryTitle release]; subCategoryTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                    (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];

Comment: Yes, it would solve the leaking problem. Yet you might want to consider only creating object for the last step.

Comment: also i have tthis statement at the end   return [subCategoryTitle autorelease];

Comment: That's good, but it only relates to the last object assigned to `subCategoryTitle`, not to those you already leaked.

Comment: can you please show me how should i handle this funtion properly(Yet you might want to consider only creating object for the last step)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11138/discussion-between-binyamin-sharet-and-user198725878)